# use tar to backup without deleting files with the same timestamp

Tags: backup, tar

as title, is there any way to backup file by tar, and do not overwrite the file with the same name and the same timestamp?
Currently I use tar in this way:

> tar cvf - source/ | tar xvf - -C dest/

I saw some discussion mentioned

> tar --backup=simple

but this does not update file with different timestamp.

I am using rsync but it is very slow

Comment: This might help: [Options Controlling the Overwriting of Existing Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html)

Comment: Thanks, it gave me some thoughts and I found the solution in the tar man page, using the `--keep-newer-files` can prevent overwriting the files with the same name and the same timestamp.